# System.setProperty for logger not modified after static method call in another class

Tags: java, jvm, system-properties

I have a program in which I need to set the logger formatting, but since there are several entry points (I don't control all of them) I want to place the `System.setProperty()` call in the constructor of the class where all of the entry points converge.

#### Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String foo = "bar";
    String baz = "boo";
    static final String FORMATTER_CONFIG = "%1$tb %1$td, %1$tY %1$tr %4$s: %5$s%n";

    SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
    sc.method1(foo);
    sc.method2(baz);

    try {
        SomeOtherClass soc = SomeOtherClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {;
    }
    // Next line will update the property of the logging formatter for this instance
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", FORMATTER_CONFIG);
    MyThirdClass mtc = MyThirdClass.getStaticMethod(foo, baz);

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myProject.main");
    Handler h = new FileHandler("LogHere.txt");
    h.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    logger.addHandler(h);
    logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    logger.info("Info level log");
    logger.fine("Fine level log");
    logger.finer("Finer level log");
    logger.finest("Finest level log");
}
```

#### Constructor of `MyThirdClass`:

```
public MyThirdClass() throws SecurityException {
    this.classStaticVar = EntirelyDifferentClass.getVar();
    logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    Handler h = null;
    try {
        h = new FileHandler("MTC_LogHere.txt");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.warning("Failed to initialize custom FileHandler for MTC_LogHere.txt");
    }
    h.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    logger.addHandler(h);
    logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
}
```

I want to put the call to `System.setProperty` as the first line of the constructor in `MyThirdClass` (before the call to `EntirelyDifferentClass`) but when I do the logging is not formatted according to the custom rules. If I leave it right where it is, the line before the call to `MyThirdClass` in the main method, it works as intended. Note that I've also tried putting the code block for `System.setProperty` in the `getStaticMethod()` method.

I understand that the `system.properties` are all static variables, so I have to believe that whatever is happening in the JVM during the method call to `MyThirdClass.getStaticMethod` is locking in the static properties before I can change it.

1. Am I understanding what is happening in the JVM correctly?
2. Since I don't control all entry points in the actual production
   version of this program, and I also don't control the compile
   settings nor can I issue a -Djava line command to set the properties
   that way (which I've also verified will work) I need to be able to
   do this programmatically in `MyThirdClass`. What am I
   missing/overlooking, or am I just out of luck?

Comment: you might write this as an answer to your own question and accept it later.

Comment: You are aware that you don't need to do this? That the `LogManager` exists? That you can call actual methods?

Comment: I posted the answer you left in your question as an official answer below, after you did not do so following a suggestion in a comment above.
I am not trying to take any credit away from you buddy. Say the word and I will delete the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was originally edited into the question above by the OP [Bryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9710693/bryan), I have posted this here and requested him to do so himself:

> For anyone wanting to know the answer, I added a static block at the
> class level of `MyThirdClass`:
>
> ```
>   protected static Logger logger = null;
>
>   static {
>       System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", FORMATTER_CONFIG);
>       logger = Logger.getLogger("myProject.MyThirdClass");
>       Handler h = null;
>       try {
>          h = new FileHandler("LogHere.txt");
>       }
>       catch (Exception ex) {
>           System.out.println("Exception");
>       }
>       h.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
>       logger.addHandler(h);
>       logger.setLevel(Constants.LOGGING_LEVEL);
>   }
> ```

Comment: for anyone wondering if cutting the answer from the question is an OK thing to do.. yes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309552/is-it-acceptable-to-take-the-self-answer-from-an-edit-to-the-question-and-post-i

Answer (score 0):

When you call a static method, such as `getStaticMethod()` in your case, an instance of the class is not created, and therefore the constructor is not called.

Try putting `System.setProperty()` in the static method instead of in the constructor.

For example:

```
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass.staticMethod();

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        logger.info("Info level log");
    }
}

public class SomeClass {
    public static void staticMethod() {
        final String FORMATTER_CONFIG = "%1$tb %1$td, %1$tY %1$tr %4$s: %5$s%n";
        System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", FORMATTER_CONFIG);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it, and noted in the original question. Last sentence of paragraph after the code block for MyThirdClass.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of this case?

Comment: Imagine the first lines of the `getStaticMethod(String foo, String bar)` looking exactly like MyThirdClass above, without the call to EntirelyDifferentClass.

Comment: It did not. See my edit to the original question. Apparently **something** the JVM (I assume JVM?) is doing when calling the static method is setting the static value in system properties to a default value. I was able to catch it before it got set using a static block at the class level. Now I need to figure out if it's going to work with my application and the logger now being static.